# session taken and lost

Tags: php, session

Please, a little help to solve this problem.
The scenario is complex, but in the essence it is:

1. content of first-file.php

   ```
   <?php

   session_start();

   $_SESSION['s_Foo'] = "pippo";

   /* this is only a twisted way of producing the header('location: second-file.php'), because unfortunately often I obtain the error "headers already sent". */

   echo "<!DOCTYPE html><html>";

   echo "<head>&#60;meta charset='utf-8'>&#60;/head>";

   echo "<body onload='go()'>";

   echo "<script>function go(){location.replace(\"second-file.php\")}</script>";

   echo "</body>";

   echo "</html>";

   exit;

   ?>
   ```
2. content of second-file.php

   ```
   <?php

   session_start();

   $foo = isset($_SESSION['s_Foo']) ? $_SESSION['s_Foo'] : "nothing";

   echo $foo;

   ...
   here a line that require to use $_SESSION['s_Foo']

   ?>
   ```

Now, I read (in the secon file) "*pippo*", but only for half or one second...
Then disappears "*pippo*", and it is written "*nothing*" whit the php log "Notice: Undefined index: s_Foo in [...]/second-file.php on line 4

Thank you in advance,
Francesco

.

Comment: try this 1) make you PHP page `UTF-8 without BOM` 2) put `session_start` right after opening php tag (no blank line) 3) add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` after that 4) run page again -> what does it say ?

Comment: you can also check [THIS](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php)